# Embedded C - USB stack, arm-none-eabi-gcc settings and Matlab interface

Tags: usb, c, arm, matlab, cortex-m

I am using [LPCOpen](https://www.nxp.com/pages/design/microcontrollers-developer-resources/lpcopen-libraries-and-examples/lpcopen-software-development-platform-lpc43xx:LPCOPEN-SOFTWARE-FOR-LPC43XX) (latest realese available for LPC4370) and the usb stack provided within it.
I need to build a simple FSM to control the mcu with Matlab and send data from Matlab to the mcu and from the mcu to Maltab. ([here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437041/cortex-m-lpcopen-usb-vcom-basics-proper-way-to-build-a-simple-fsm) another question from me on the same topic)

- FSM: I'm using char as commands (e.g. Matlab sends 'o', the mcu starts data output
- DATA TRANSFER: I'm sending data in bulks of 128 32 bits integers each

So as far as I understood I need to implement a CDC USB host.

LPCOPen provides the following examples to start with (and no documentation other than read-me files)

- **usbd_rom_cdc_uart**: The example shows how to us USBD ROM stack to creates a CDC UART/Serial port bridge.
- **usbd_rom_cdc_vcom** The example shows how to us USBD ROM stack to creates a virtual comm port.
- **usbd_rom_dfu_composite**
- **usbd_rom_hid_generic**
- **usbd_rom_hid_keyboard**
- **usbd_rom_hid_mouse**
- **usbd_rom_hid_sio**
- **usbd_rom_libusb**: The example shows how to us USBD ROM stack to create simple USB data pipes.
  This example provides libusbdevice encapsulation with simple to use API for
  non-USB experienced users to develop simple data-pipe applications.
  The example is tested with http://libusbk.sourceforge.net host side applications.
  The examples also shows how to handle WCID requests to install libusbk driver.
  Check https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/WCID-Devices for more details.
- **usbd_rom_msc_ram**: The example shows how to use USBD ROM stack to creates a USB MSC example
  that uses RAM. The device appears as unformatted disk with size as 32KB.

Among the above are two examples which I think could use: **usbd_rom_cdc_uart** and **usbd_rom_cdc_vcom**.

**usbd_rom_cdc_uart** is enterely IRQ based and it was not clear to me how I could send/receive data.
it's main loop looks like:

```
while (1) {
    /* Sleep until next IRQ happens */
    __WFI();
}
```

So I started with **usbd_rom_cdc_vcom** which does a loop-back:

```
DEBUGSTR("USB CDC class based virtual Comm port example!\r\n");

while (1) {
    /* Check if host has connected and opened the VCOM port */
    if ((vcom_connected() != 0) && (prompt == 0)) {
        vcom_write("Hello World!!\r\n", 15);
        prompt = 1;
    }
    /* If VCOM port is opened echo whatever we receive back to host. */
    if (prompt) {
        rdCnt = vcom_bread(&g_rxBuff[0], 256);
        if (rdCnt) {
            vcom_write(&g_rxBuff[0], rdCnt);
        }
    }
    /* Sleep until next IRQ happens */
    __WFI();
}
```

So I tested this on a terminal and then tried to move on and use Matlab.

What I found more difficult doing the small messaging.
Here some code snippets.
From matlab side:

```
fwrite(serial_object, K_COEFF,  'int32');
if K_COEFF ~= fread(serial_object, 1, 'int32')
 error('out of sync');
 end
pause(0.0005)

fwrite(serial_object, L_COEFF,  'int32');
 if L_COEFF ~= fread(serial_object, 1, 'int32')
 error('out of sync');
end
pause(0.0005)
```

C counterpart:

```
/*SET K*/
while(!rdCnt)
{rdCnt = vcom_bread(&param_rxBuff, sizeof(int32_t));}
K_COEFF = param_rxBuff;
vcom_write((uint8_t*)&param_rxBuff, sizeof(int32_t));
param_rxBuff = 0;
rdCnt = 0;

/*SET L*/
while(!rdCnt)
{rdCnt = vcom_bread(&param_rxBuff, sizeof(int32_t));}
L_COEFF = param_rxBuff;
vcom_write((uint8_t*)&param_rxBuff, sizeof(int32_t));
param_rxBuff = 0;
rdCnt = 0;
```

where `vcom_bread` and `vcom_write` are usb stack calls.

Now, this is working. Sometimes.

Some other times the communication goes "out of sync" and Matlab just hangs on printing warnings about the microcontroller not responding.
What I noticed is that this depends largely on timing and so also on the compiler settings: I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc and the more I optimize (e.g. O3) the less it works.
Does anyone have similar experience of some kind? What should be the best way of interfacing Matlab with an mcu?

EDIT1:
As suggested I tried to modify the matlab side:

```
fwrite(...)
pause(0.001);
flushoutput(serial_object);
flushinput(serial_object);
fread(...)
```

Unfortunately to no avail. Matlab is still warning me about unsuccessful read.

Comment: It's unclear here if you are using a fully buffered virtual serial channel with blocking reads, or something that more closely reflects what is actually going on at packet level, but you should probably start by figuring that out, and adapting the code to handle what can legitimately happen in each case.  You might also use something like wireshark in USB monitoring mode.  It's also unclear if your embedded USB stack will "pump itself in the background automatically" via interrupts alone or if you are obligated to call into it periodically to let it do so.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, thanks for the comment.
I must say I'm quite a newbie when it comes to USB.
What I know from the example that I started with is that I should use those 2 functions to read/write and that the stack operates in interrupt mode. Infact I can see an USB IRQ handler into the code.
Does it make sense that the reliability depends on compiler settings like optimization?

Comment: Again, you need to take time to understand the actual behavior specified for the APIs you use.  And use something like wireshark to see what is actually happening on the USB bus.  You path to a solution will be to either recognize *invalid assumptions* by *inspection* of the code or to identify the *specific* undesired behavior in a log of communication and then trace that back to the ultimate cause.

Comment: Try putting a pause in between the write and the read on the MATLAB side, possibly a flush too, as the underlying O/S will have USB buffering in place.  From a USB perspective, there will probably be at least one IN/NAK microframe between the RX and TX, so make the delay at least 250 us (2 microframes) and maybe as much as 1ms, just to be sure (assuming it's USB 2.0).

Comment: @EvilDogPie thanks for the reply. 
I update the question with this try. ALso, I investigated a bit more the timing and it seems that matlab is slower than my mcu. You think my measurmenet could be correct?

Comment: @EvilDogPie - **No! simply putting in delays is truly *terrible* practice**, the code should wait a reasonable amount of time for an answer, and if not declare a synchronization failure and do something to reset the conversation.   **The asker here keeps avoiding debugging their actual issue**, playing with delays is just going to lead to unreliability in situations missed by testing.

Comment: Also flushinput() is very inappropriate - that would *discard* any timely reply.  The only place you'd want to do that is if you've given up and are starting over with a new query to the embedded device - one of the rare cases where a fixed delay could be appropriate would be to wait for any last out-of-sync garbage, then flush the input buffer, and then begin again with a new request.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I get your point, but unfortunately I don't know how could I do better if not spending weeks trying to learn how to build a usb driver to debug one that should work since is provided by NXP itself. I tried wireshark but I'm not able to caputer packets from my mcu and I know too little about usb to thinker seriously with that. I just need this communication in order to do some tests, and I know I'm not following best practice guidelines, but unfortunately I have no time to study the protocol from gorund-up.

Comment: @ChrisStratton may I ask you one thing? As you can see I'm trying to sends integers (parameters and commands for my FSM) using single calls of fwrite/fread. Is this bad practice too when using a usb-stack?

Comment: Lots of little calls are probably *slow* but for many uses aren't necessarily bad if you have sound synchronization logic.  Note you could have a much simpler synchronization scheme if you used USB packets directly, as they give you a sense of framing that you won't really have with a serial API.  But all you really need to do here is write sound wait for a result logic, make sure you handle the possibility of only some but not all bytes initially being available, and have some sort of giveup and retry in the case of gross failure.

Comment: Ok thanks. What kind of sync scheme would you define sound for usb communication? As you can see what I do is: send command w/ Matlab -> loop it back w/ mcu -> check that the answer is correct w/ Matlab.
What I found is that often the mcu is way faster than matlab and for some reason matlab can not catch the answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree that the delay is not the right thing to do in production code, but to investigate why the problem is occurring it may yield clues.  The embedded USB driver that the o/p is using is fairly simple and should (massive assumption) issue the bulk IN packet containing the data in a fairly timely manner, relative to MATLAB.  Also, I meant that he should try to flush the Write (OUT) stream, not the read stream.  USB drivers like to cache bulk data to send multiple small packets (relative to higher layer) in a single bulk transaction.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It appears that flushing the stream in MATLAB just clears out the buffer, rather than making sure that anything pending has been sent.  I've had similar problems in C++, where calling fflush() on the stream makes sure that the data is gone before the next statement is executed.

Comment: I tried to add as much info as I could. I'd gladly upload the files, but I think it's not possible here on stackexchange.

Comment: @EvilDogPie actually my experience has been that virtual serial drivers usually don't cache short writes beyond the next opportunity to put a packet on the bus - if you do an actual write() syscall a packet tends to go out with that many bytes (up to the limit).  But something like an fwrite() is more likely a *stream* function with buffering in the application, and what the flush operation would do is flush the in-application buffer with write(s) to the actual file descriptor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I hadn't considered that the buffering would be higher up in the stream implementation, but that makes a lot more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Read the Matlab documentation guidance on serial coms https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/writing-and-reading-data.html pay particular attention to synchronous vs. asynchronous modes and the Timeout property. The line-oriented textual examples won't apply (unless you change your format) but the binary one would. With an appropriate timeout you should be able to do a read that will block until it gets your data or gives up. Or you can check the available bytes yourself while checking the time, do the read once you see enough or make your own decision to give up.

Comment: Ok @ChrisStratton I carefully read the document you suggested and I realize I need to dig more into USB. 
As I understood Matlab needs BaudRate and Terminator setting. But I am not able to figure out which my usb driver on the mcu is using: how do i found them among the descriptors? I searched for baudrate everywhere but no luck

Comment: BaudRate and Terminator settings are not relevant to USB.You can probably leave them with default values, or use 115,200 and CR/LF (if Windows) or LF (if Linux) if something is required.  The documentation in that link is for a generic serial stream.  The USB device class that you have implemented on the MCU is a CDC (Communications Device Class) based interface.  When you connect this to your PC the host O/S loads a class driver that make is look like a serial (COM) port to the rest of the system.  MATLAB allows the COM device to be opened as a serial stream. ctd...

Comment: You can use all of the serial stream functions and properties, even though some are not actually used.  You may want to check the BytesAvailable property before reading bytes from the stream.  That documentation that Chris Stratton linked is good.

Comment: Terminator would be relevant even to USB if you had a textual scheme and were using line oriented functions, but you have a binary scheme.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the only text based thing that I do I sending chars as commands for the mcu and send them back for Matlab to check

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think I found something useful. My firmware is issuing 3 write operation one after the other and I found out that at 512 bytes each I was probably filling the buffer befor matlab had the time to read.
In my driver sources I only find definitions like #define VCOM_RX_BUF_SZ      512. Not a single line with TX_BUF. Should I assume the TX_BUFF is 512 bytes?

Comment: You should never assume anything. Study the actual code.  There may not even be any buffering of output.